# Tweepy won't import to Jupyter notebook on azure

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tweepy

I'm trying to write in a microsoft azure jupyter python notebook and I am receiving an error when I try to import the Tweepy module.

Please take a look at the simple code below and let me know your thoughts. Thank you. I'm working on a chromebook if that helps, but I'm not sure it's relevant.

```
import tweepy as tw
tw.__version__
```

Here's what comes up:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-453b41c5a7f9> in <module>()
----> 1 import tweepy as tw
      2 tw.__version__

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy'
```

Comment: Have you installed the module?

Comment: Didn't think I need to on an azure notebook, I think the other modules (pandas, numpy, matplotlib, etc.) imported without installation.

Comment: I haven't used them specifically, but it looks like it uses Anaconda and that doesn't ship with tweepy.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Azure Notebooks docs](https://notebooks.azure.com/help/jupyter-notebooks/package-installation/python):

> The simplest way to install packages is to do it from within a Jupyter Python notebook. Inside of the notebook your path will be setup to have both pip and conda on it pointing to the proper version of Python. So inside of a notebook you can simply do:
>
> `!pip install <pkg name>`
>
> or
>
> `!conda install <pkg name> -y`

So just first execute a cell that contains:

```
!pip install tweepy
```

and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I was trying to use tweepy. You can try using these commands instead:
`from tweepy import OAuthHandler from tweepy import API from tweepy import Cursor`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31166141)